# Django admin screen doesn't show entities by name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

[image: The Admin screen]

In Django I made an entity called User in Models, when I made it visible in the Admin page it shows it only as User Object instead of by the id or name, how can I change this?

How can I change this to something intuitive ? Like the ID or the Name of the user ?

models.py shows:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = ( ('A','First AC'), ('B','Second AC'), ('C','Third AC'), ('D','Sleeper') )
```

Additionally how come the choices in category do not appear on the Add User screen ?

[image: Add User]

The admin.py for this app[named 'data'] has:

```
from django.contrib import admin    
from data.models import User
admin.site.register(User)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include a [`__str__` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#str) in your model that returns the string that you want to show:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = ( ('A','First AC'), ('B','Second AC'), ('C','Third AC'), ('D','Sleeper') )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.user_id)
```

Comment: For Python 3? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#other-model-instance-methods